# $_GET variables - Why is previous data not hiding?

Tags: php, variables, get, hide

I am creating a website that contains categories, subcategories and listings. Upon clicking on a category i.e. computing the page changes to show all subcategories from the database that are in the computing category. Then when a subcategory is clicked listings for that subcategory are displayed and the subcategory selection is posted to the URL. Then when a listing is clicked the same thing happens. That is all ok but when I try to display the listing details it should hide the listings but this is not happening. Does anyone have any idea why? The code I am using is below:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
?>

<h1> Computing </h1>

<?php
$subcategory = 'Computing';

if (isset($_GET['subcategory']) && trim($_GET['subcategory']) != '') {
    $subcategory = trim($_GET['subcategory']) != '';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category = '$subcategory' ORDER BY subcategory ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql);
$catNo = 1;
echo "<table class='categorytable'> <tr class='categoryrow'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<td class="categorydata"><a href="computing.php?subcategory=' . strtolower($row['subcategory']) . '"><img class="catimg" src="' . $row['subcategory_img_path'] . '" border="0" /></br>' . $row['subcategory'] . '</a></td>';
    if ($catNo % 3 == 0) {

        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $catNo++;
}
echo "</tr> </table>";
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['subcategory'])) {
    $subcat = $_GET['subcategory'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE subcategory = '$subcat' ORDER BY title ASC";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql2);
    $catNo = 1;
    echo "<table class='categorytable'> <tr class='categoryrow'>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo '<td class="categorydata"><a href="computing.php?subcategory=' . $subcat . '&' . 'listingid=' . ($row2['listing_id']) . '"><img class="catimg" src="' . $row2['main_image'] . '" border="0" /></br>' . $row2['title'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>' . ' ' . $row2['cogs'] . ' per week' . '</a></td>';
        if ($catNo % 3 == 0) {

            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        $catNo++;
    }
    var_dump($_GET);


    echo "</tr> </table>";
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['listingid'])) {
        $listingid = $_GET['listingid'];

        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE listing_id='$listingid'";
        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql3);
        while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
            //whatever your values are
            echo $row3['description'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>

</br>

<?php
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

I am aware that php_ functions are deprecated and security hasn't been taken into consideration yet but will worry about this when i have everything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the while part into an `if`.

```
if(!isset($_GET['subcategory'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category = '$subcategory' ORDER BY subcategory ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql);
$catNo = 1;
echo "<table class='categorytable'> <tr class='categoryrow'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<td class="categorydata"><a href="computing.php?subcategory=' . strtolower($row['subcategory']) . '"><img class="catimg" src="' . $row['subcategory_img_path'] . '" border="0" /></br>' . $row['subcategory'] . '</a></td>';
    if ($catNo % 3 == 0) {

        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $catNo++;
}
echo "</tr> </table>";

}
```

Comment: The subcategory bit seems to be working ok but i have changed the $subcategory thing you suggested. The issue is with hiding the listings when the listing is clicked

Comment: @StevenTrainor That's easy. Just put the listing codes into an `if (!isset($_GET['subcategory'])) {/*put it here*/}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean :/

Comment: I've added that before each of the sql queries but hasn't fixed the issue with listings being hidden when a listing is clicked but it is working when a subcategory is clicked (subcategories are hidden and listings are displayed)

Comment: @StevenTrainor when the listing is clicked, what's the variable in URL? Put it into that `if` too.

Comment: that variable is called listingid and is in the sql3 code towards the bottom of the original code posted above. Are you saying to put both in to the same if statement? Thanks for your time on this by the way

Comment: Exactly. Put it to the same statement. i.e, if (!isset($_GET['subcategory']) && !isset($_GET['listingid'])) {/*put your listing loop here*/}

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is fine just need to fix this Line:

```
if (isset($_GET['subcategory']) && trim($_GET['subcategory']) != '') {
    $subcategory = trim($_GET['subcategory']) != '';
}
```

Why are you assigning a boolean value to `$subcategory` var and then firing a query on it. The statement:

```
$subcategory = trim($_GET['subcategory']) != '';
```

Will give 1 (`TRUE`) if `$_GET['subcategory']` is non null or not blank.
You should Change the line to:

```
if (isset($_GET['subcategory']) && trim($_GET['subcategory']) != '') {
    $subcategory = trim($_GET['subcategory']);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

i think i got a better solution. Check this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['subcategory'])) {
    $subcat = $_GET['subcategory'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE subcategory = '$subcat' ORDER BY title ASC";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql2);
    $catNo = 1;
    echo "<table class='categorytable'> <tr class='categoryrow'>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo '<td class="categorydata"><a href="computing.php?listingid=' . ($row2['listing_id']) . '"><img class="catimg" src="' . $row2['main_image'] . '" border="0" /></br>' . $row2['title'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>' . ' ' . $row2['cogs'] . ' per week' . '</a></td>';
        if ($catNo % 3 == 0) {

            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        $catNo++;
    }
    var_dump($_GET);


    echo "</tr> </table>";
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['listingid'])) {
    $listingid = $_GET['listingid'];

    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE listing_id='$listingid'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql3);
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
        //whatever your values are
        echo $row3['description'] . "<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

In here I changed the code to match a way of view that in my opinion is the closest one to fix your code. As the listings database table are not selected depending in the subcategory name, what we can do with this is to separate the listings block from the subcategories block with the `if(isset($_GET['subcategory']))` if block ending before `if (isset($_GET['listingid']))` and removing the subcategory GET variable from the URL when you call the listing so you don't run the subcategory if block.
What happens is that listings are called when you feed the URL with subcategory variable in the URL and separately not feeding the subcategory to the URL when trying to display the listing you are showing and hiding those stages of the page.
You don't need a subcategory value to show a listing, only listings list, and you should then only care about the listingid GET variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code:

```
<?php
$category = 'Computing';

if (isset($_GET['category']) && trim($_GET['category']) != '') {
    $category = trim($_GET['category']);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category = '$category' ORDER BY category ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql);
$catNo = 1;
echo "<table class='categorytable'> <tr class='categoryrow'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<td class="categorydata"><a href="computing.php?category='. $category.'&subcategory=' . strtolower($row['subcategory']) . '"><img class="catimg" src="' . $row['subcategory_img_path'] . '" border="0" /></br>' . $row['subcategory'] . '</a></td>';
    if ($catNo % 3 == 0) {

        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $catNo++;
}
echo "</tr> </table>";
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['subcategory'])) {
    $subcat = $_GET['subcategory'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE subcategory = '$subcat' ORDER BY title ASC";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql2);
    $catNo = 1;
    echo "<table class='categorytable'> <tr class='categoryrow'>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo '<td class="categorydata"><a href="computing.php?category='. $category.'&subcategory=' . $subcat . '&' . 'listingid=' . ($row2['listing_id']) . '"><img class="catimg" src="' . $row2['main_image'] . '" border="0" /></br>' . $row2['title'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>' . ' ' . $row2['cogs'] . ' per week' . '</a></td>';
        if ($catNo % 3 == 0) {

            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        $catNo++;
    }
    var_dump($_GET);


    echo "</tr> </table>";
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['listingid'])) {
        $listingid = $_GET['listingid'];

        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE listing_id='$listingid'";
        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql3);
        while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
            //whatever your values are
            echo $row3['description'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>

</br>

<?php
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with zairwolf, basically Steven you need a way to flag when you should display the listing, a bit of planning on the structure of your page load would probably help.  The below is a possible flow for you to implement which may improve your implementation if I understand what you need.

```
//Proposed layout

function show_categories () {
   //draw the categories down the left side of screen with "/?category={$record->CATEGORYID}" in anchor href
}

function show_subcategories ($category) {
  //select the subcategories based on the passed category and output also with href as you have already
}

function show_listings ($subcategory) {
  //select all the listings based on the sub category sent here
}

//always show the categories ?
show_categories ();

//other logic when to display sub categories or listings
if ($_REQUEST["subcategory"]) { 
 show_listings ($_REQUEST["subcategory"]);
} else {
 show_subcategories ($_REQUEST["category"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $_POST method, it will work